# Serilog custom outputTemplate

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

I was looking for custom output template format for logging

sample output template : "{\"time\":\"+ \",\"severity\":\"{Level:u}\",\"machine\":\"{MachineName}\", \"x-Correlation-ID\":\"{CorrelationID}\"}"

It is always expecting first filed value as "+" value, if that filed not exists means it is not replacing next property value({Level:u}).

For above template output : `{"time":"+ ","severity":"INFORMATION","machine":"xxxxxx", "x-Correlation-ID":"e5b9c851-de56-42d9-b414-9d7108d2ebcf"}`

If first field value other than "+" value, output as follows : {"time":"test ","severity":"{Level:u}","machine":"xxxxxx", "x-Correlation-ID":"f6133a7e-ea4f-4bde-8200-798d5346d3ce"}

RollingFileAlternate sink used to log WriteTo.Async(w => w.RollingFileAlternate(logFilePath.ToString(), outputTemplate: logOutputTemplate, fileSizeLimitBytes: rollingFilesSize, retainedFileCountLimit: null))

how to remove first property with out effecting other output template properties.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably going to have to implement a custom `ITextFormatter` that implements the logic that you need, in order to create the corresponding output you want.

You can see how the the default ones ([`CompactJsonFormatter.cs`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Formatting.Compact/Formatting/Compact/CompactJsonFormatter.cs)and [`RenderedCompactJsonFormatter.cs`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Formatting.Compact/Formatting/Compact/RenderedCompactJsonFormatter.cs)) are implemented, and adapt the code to work how you need it.

```
public class YourCustomJsonFormatter : ITextFormatter
{
    public void Format(LogEvent logEvent, TextWriter output)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console(new YourCustomJsonFormatter())
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Hi @Caio,  Thank you for your comment, custom ITextFormatter not supporting with serilog output template.

Comment: @Srini I'm not sure I understand your comment above. Which sink are you using that does not support `ITextFormatter`?